# Laravel, copy tables from one database to other

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm working on a SaaS project. With different client requests for more fields or less etc, i believe it would be helpful instead of just keep growing on already created tables, divide the tables that could indeed grow into separate databases per client. To do so, it would involve recreating the tables to X connection which is already set, and creating a bunch of tables making migrations huge.

My question is if there is a method to copy table `example_table` from database A to database B keeping the data using the normal migrations, or if i would be better off using some DBMS to make the templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a raw query

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use DB;

class MyNewTable extends Migration {

   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       DB::statement('CREATE TABLE conection2.newtable LIKE system.oldtable; ');
   }


   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::connection('conection2')->drop('newtable');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that does seem the best path to follow as it keeps indexes. Also, check my edit because of the multiple db s

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to add that part. Approved the edit thanks!

Comment: It doesn't copy the data as per original question

Comment: @dgpro to copy the data aswell you will need to do the following: `INSERT INTO newtable  SELECT * FROM oldtable GROUP BY ID;`